# how to block specific IP addreess with mod_security after specific times in one minute

Tags: mod-security2

Well, normally I'm not the person intended to do that, I'm a PHP developer and have general knowledge about Apache and security administration, but for emergency only I have to do this now.

I'm in a situation where I need to write Mod_Security rule that:

```
 - blocks specific IP address from access our website,
 - for 5 minutes
 - if it try to call more than 10 links in less than 10 seconds
```

Can I achieve that writing a mod_security rule?

Comment: sorry, forget to mention that our server uses Apache 2.4.7 and Mod_security2 with custom security rules on Ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModSecurity can do this, but wouldn't suggest it.

Have a look at the DOS rules in the OWASP CRS: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/experimental_rules/modsecurity_crs_11_dos_protection.conf. Note these do depend on set up in the main CRS setup file: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf.example

However ModSecurity collections are not the most stable especially for high volume. You run into problems with multiple threads accessing the collection file. Also might find you have to delete the collection file regularly (e.g. every 24 hours) to prevent it continually growing.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is exactly what i mean. We don't try to prevent a real DOS attack. Its just for emergency as i mentioned where  I need to block someone specifically from trying to make minor problems to our website. When our security admin back in action he will take care of this.